# flask_restx - api.expect from two sources for swagger

Tags: flask, flask-restful, flask-restx

Hei there!

I have a flask restx api and I have an endpoint that essentially needs to do the following

```
filters = api.model('filters', {
  x = fields.Raw('x')
}

parser = reqparse.RequestParser()
parser.add_argument('b', type=int, location='args')

class Process(Resource):
  @api.expect(filters)
  @api.expect(parser)
  def get()
  .      
  .
```

**why?**

I have a large set of endpoints that **all** accept the same filter design, but **some** endpoints **also** need query parameters

The code works just fine, I can access the json payload and the query parameters inside the method.

**The problem**
I need everything documented by swagger but I need to "mix" the `api.model` object with the `parser` object into the `@api.expect()`

Answer (score 0):

@api.expect(filters,parser) should work